# Sanity checking an Oauth2 Implementation

Tags: api, oauth, oauth-2.0, restful-authentication

I've designed a RESTful inspired API for my website (called CLMS) that I'd like to secure using oauth2 (not oauth1). After trawling through the web, I've come up with this... Could someone sanity check this for me, and answer my q's?

**Context.**

I have a multi-tenanted system (named CLMS) that is both the Authorization Server and the Resource Server. The CLMS API will be used by specific, trusted partners (let's call an example one **3PS**).

**Flow:**

**Application Credentials**

Before any partner (3PS) can use the CLMS API, they must acquire unique and confidential credentials from the CLMS out-of-band. These credentials include a client_id and a client_secret. These details will be used to authenticate API calls using the OAuth 2.0 protocol.

The client_id should map to a single user within the CLMS system. If 3PS is required to access specific information, then the client_id should be mapped to a user in the CLMS that already has suitable permissions.

**Access token request**

Once a partner (3PS) has received these credentials they may use them to request an oauth2 bearer token from our CLMS token endpoint: 
.../v1/oauth2/token

The CLMS token endpoint is needed to authenticate your access token request (using HTTP Basic Auth) with your application credentials obtained as described above. The ‘client_id’ and ‘client_secret’ becomes your user-id and password in HTTP Basic Auth.

The CLMS, acting as the “authorization server”, verifies your application credentials and returns an access token. The specific kind of access token that CLMS provides is a “Bearer Token”.

**API request authentication**

When the 3PS makes API calls, the request is made by adding the access token in the ‘Authorization’ header using the following syntax (as defined in the OAuth 2.0 protocol):

Authorization: {tokenType} {accessToken}
Example: Authorization: Bearer EEwJ6tF9x5...4599F

**Questions**

1. Does this make sense as an oauth2 implementation?
2. Is it OK to use HTTP basic auth to request an access token?
3. Am I right in assuming that I can map bearer tokens against individual CLMS user permissions that already exist in my system.
4. Is this called 'Client Credentials' grant?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, if you have a limited set of clients (partners), it would be a good idea to manually generate their client id and secret and provide it to them.

1-Does this make sense as an oauth2 implementation?

Yes it does, but it only covers the 'client-credentials' grant scenario.

2-Is it OK to use HTTP basic auth to request an access token?

This makes no sense. Assuming you already have clients registered, this is simply an additional level of authentication which is not really required. Any unauthorized request to your webservices will be rejected for want of a valid access token.

3-Am I right in assuming that I can map bearer tokens against individual CLMS user permissions that already exist in my system.

Yes you can. I advise to utilize the 'scope' functionality provided by Oauth2 for this, where you can associate 'scopes' to an access token, providing them access to certain data.

4-Is this called 'Client Credentials' grant?

Yes it is.

Beyond the above :

- Run this only over HTTPS. You don't want your client id/secret or access tokens to be compromised over unsafe public networks over plain text HTTP
- There could be certain 'scopes' for which you might want to implement the user authorization flow for a 'login'